# I want to search a file of tweets to find the most popular hashtags used

Tags: python, word-cloud

For a python project I have been asked to collect tweets over a certain period of time about a certain topic. I now have a file with hundreds of tweets. How do I search for most popular hashtags in that file to create a word cloud?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that your corpus is stored as a list and all the special characters are already removed. I am using functions from `sklearn`

```py
corpus = ['the text of your tweet','quote in it']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
v = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
dense = v.todense()
final_list = dense.tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns=names)
Cloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=50).generate_from_frequencies(df.T.sum(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose that you have the ID of each tweet
you need to send a GET request to this url
"
https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/6n-3uwmsFr53-5z_w5FTVw/TweetDetail?variables=%7B%22focalTweetId<YOUR_TWEET_ID> with_rux_injections%22%3Afalse%2C%22includePromotedContent%22%3Atrue%2C%22withCommunity%22%3Atrue%2C%22withQuickPromoteEligibilityTweetFields%22%3Atrue%2C%22withBirdwatchNotes%22%3Afalse%2C%22withSuperFollowsUserFields%22%3Atrue%2C%22withDownvotePerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsMetadata%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsPerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withSuperFollowsTweetFields%22%3Atrue%2C%22withVoice%22%3Atrue%2C%22withV2Timeline%22%3Atrue%2C%22__fs_responsive_web_like_by_author_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22__fs_dont_mention_me_view_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22__fs_interactive_text_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22__fs_responsive_web_uc_gql_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22__fs_responsive_web_edit_tweet_api_enabled%22%3Afalse%7D
"

**Note**: the url looks not good because of the line breaks but
hopefully you understood

and the very first kind of param is focalTweetId, which is the id of the tweet, this API call will return a data object where you'll find all infos about a tweet

```
const response = await fetch(url)
console.log(response.data.instructions[0].entries[0].content.itemContent.tweet_results.result.legacy.retweet_count)
```

I did this in JavaScript, so you can do it in python with

```
response = requests.get(url)
# ...
```

this will return the retweet_count, and there are a lot of other usefull data you can use